# Eclipse run configurations empty with TestNG and eCobertura

Tags: eclipse, testng, ecobertura

My run configurations tab comes up empty: I can't see anything but the ***Name*** textbox and the ***Run*** and ***Cancel*** buttons.

I've checked the answers and restarted, refreshed, cleaned, rebuilt and even removed the launch entries and relaunched, but I still can't get any of the tabs to add VM arguments, ***Main***, etc.

What do I do?

As asked by @greg-449 The most recent log entry message when i checked my run configurations is this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.ui 4 0 2014-08-08 08:29:54.189
!MESSAGE Tab group extension: org.testng.eclipse.launchConfigurationTabGroup.testng for         type org.testng.eclipse.launchconfig for the * mode has been replaced by extension: ecobertura.ui.launching.config.TestNGConfigurationTabGroup
```

Comment: Does the same happen with a new download of eclipse?

Comment: Any messages in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Answer (score -1):

After a reinstall of eclipse when I found the problem persisted, I found that it is a bug with eCobertura which causes the launch configurations to be empty.

You can find details on it here where it has been logged as a bug: [No launch configuration with testNG plugin](https://bitbucket.org/jmhofer/ecobertura/issue/3/no-launch-configuration-with-testng-plugin)